# asp.net gridview weird behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am facing a strange problem when using the gridview control in ASP.NET. I am using paging in it.

The second column in the grid is an "Order status" column which contains values such as "D", "S", etc. The "D" and "S" are database values representing "Delivered" and "Shipped". We are using these representations to save space in the database.

Now, while displaying it in the GridView, I would like it to be displayed as "Displayed" or "Shipped" instead of the "D" and "S" which comes as part of the data source. When loading the page for the first time, I am handling it by getting the rows of the current page and changing the "D" and "S" of cells with "Delivered" and "Shipped" with the help of the Page Load Event.

But, the problem occurs when I go to the next page using the paging controls of the grid view.

The values in the "Order Status" column doesn't get updated to the "D" and "S" in the second page and hence my function will fail to pick them up and fail to convert them to "Delivered" and "Shipped".

I tried the `OnPageIndexChanged` event as well. Not working even with that :(

Here's the code.

**GRIDVIEW CONTROL**

```
<asp:GridView ID="OrderGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="OrderHistory" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                CssClass="order_grid" DataKeyNames="order_id" OnPageIndexChanging="OrderGrid_PageIndexChanging">
```

**SET ORDER STATUS METHOD**

```
public void SetOrderStatus()
{
    string Delivered = "Delivered";
    string Shipped = "Shipped";
    string Processing = "Processing";

    for (int i = 0; i < OrderGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (OrderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == "D")
        {
            OrderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = Delivered;
            OrderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#127b41");
            OrderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#fdfdfd");
        }

        if (OrderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == "S")
        {
            OrderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = Shipped;
        }

        if (OrderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == "P")
        {
            OrderGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = Processing;
        }
    }
}
```

**PAGE INDEX CHANGING FUNCTION**

```
protected void OrderGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    OrderGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    OrderGrid.DataBind();

    SetOrderStatus();
    string o = OrderGrid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
}
```

I would not normally post all my code, but I am desperate to get a solution to this problem. I would greatly appreciate any help that comes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not alter your data source to return the expected display value? Your presentation layer shouldn't be responsible for translating status codes into display text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating this in the RowDataBound event.  This allows you to make an adjustment at the binding of each row.

Here's an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Comment: Hi Vikas, could you mark as answer if it worked for you?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I wanted to do it the minute it worked. But SO wants me to wait for 10 mins. Will do it as soon as it allows me :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using BoundField to represent the column in question, you could subclass BoundField, and override the FormatData method.

```
// untested code - should be approximately correct
public Class StatusBoundField:BoundField
{
     protected override string FormatDataValue(Object dataValue,bool encode)
     {
          string value = dataValue as string;
          string result = string.Empty;
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
          {
              switch(value)
              {
                  case "P": result = "Processed"; break;
                  case "S": result = "Shipped"; break;
                  case "D": result = "Delivered"; break;
                  default: result = "Unknown" // or string.Empty or throw an exception as appropriate
         }

         return base.FormatDataValue(result, encode);
     }
}
```

Then substitute your type for bound field in your gridview declaration.

e.g.

```
// replace namespace and assembly as appropriate
<%@ Register TagPrefix ="my" Namespace="WebApplication1" Assembly="WebApplication1" %>
....
<asp:GridView ID="OrderGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="OrderHistory" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
            CssClass="order_grid" DataKeyNames="order_id">
    <Columns>

        <my:StatusField DataField="OrderStatus" HeaderText="Order Status" 
            SortExpression="OrderStatus" />
....
```

This has the advantage that it is easily reusable if you need the column anywhere else in your application.

Comment: Since I had to look it up, I've added some code to show how to used the subclassed control in the aspx markup.